# Call to a member function sess_destroy() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a login procedure in Codeigniter. I refer to this link to create the form,controller and the models which are needed.But I have this errot below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUx55.png)

Can someone help me to fix this error? I have loaded the session library so I dont understand why this error is cretaed.

Comment: Did you autoload session library? And your filename should be User_authentication.php not user_authentication.php ucfirst for classes and files http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1):

Your are loading the session in the Codeigniter as a **Helper** but it's not a helper, it's a **library**.
Use:

```
     $this->load->library('session');
```

Instead of:

```
    $this->load->helper('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `session_destroy();` not `sess_destroy()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: I changed it to session_destrou but no result.

Comment: I added a link to the php documentation, take a look.

Comment: @Pipskweak sess_destroy is part of codeigniter session library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sess_destroy#CI_Session::sess_destroy

Comment: Sorry, there was nothing to show that the OP was using code igniter